# HTML elements with `aria-hidden="true"` attribute are shown

Tags: html, angular

I have an Angular web app and I use a 3rd party component that outputs an element with the `aria-hidden="true"` attribute. This element is not supposed to be visible. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden), the `aria-hidden` should be supported by all browsers and does not require additional styles to be functional.

I created this simple [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-zhukovsky-75qymf). Please give it a try and let me know if you can see the *aria hidden* element.

I also tried to create a plain HTML file to test the `aria-hidden` attribute and the element is still shown. I test the page in both Chrome and Edge. Now I wonder if `aria-hidden` is widely supported.

Comment: Turns out I accidentally remove one of the 3rd party CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

`aria-hidden="true"` is only for accessibility -- for a typical user this will have no effect.

You can add `hidden` to your element!

Otherwise `style="display: none"` or `style="visibility: hidden"` depending on your needs. The visibility option will not not change the flow of the page, so element will still affect the layout around but it just won't be visible, almost like zero opacity

---

*Also this nothing to do with Angular, you should remove the tag!*

Answer (score 0):

Tags prefixed with `aria-` are meant to help assistive technologies understand your website. As written in the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden) you linked, the `aria-hidden` tag does not actually affect the visibility on screen.

> The presence of the aria-hidden attribute hides content from assistive technology but doesn't visually hide anything.